# Will upgrading a Terraform provider make my state invalid to previous versions of that provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I have multiple projects sharing a terraform state bucket.

I am currently using Terraform's AWS provider 3.8.0, but would like to upgrade to Terraform's AWS provider 3.46.0 (which [includes some AWS resource options missing from previous versions of the AWS provider](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/19804)).

I would ideally like to initially upgrade just a single project to use Terraform's AWS provider 3.46.0, and upgrade other projects that use the state to the new AWS provider at a later time.

I have read [Terraform's doc on API compatibility](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/v1-compatibility-promises.html#providers) but it's unclear if using a new AWS provider will create a bucket that is no longer readable by other projects using the older version of that AWS provider.

**Will upgrading a Terraform provider make my state invalid to previous versions of that provider?**

Comment: By semantic versioning rules, 3.8.0-->3.46.0 is a patch update, which ensures backwards compatibility. If your state did become corrupted, then that would be a bug on the part of AWS. Since that is probably not completely reassuring, it is also worth noting that upgrades which break state are typically Terraform core upgrades, and not provider upgrades.

Comment: @MattSchuchard [Terraform doesn't quite follow semantic versioning](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/15839#issuecomment-323106524) but they seem to be close to it, so this is a good answer.